# How to install sympy package in python

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, sympy, spyder

I am a beginner to python, I wanted to symbolic computations. I came to know with sympy installation into our pc we can do symbolic computation. I have installed python 3.6 and I am using anaconda nagavitor, through which I am using spyder as an editor. now I want to install symbolic package sympy how to do that.
I checked some post which says use 'conda install sympy'. but where to type this? I typed this in spyder editor and I am getting syntax error. thankyou

Comment: Try this : 1) sudo apt-get install python3-pip  
2) sudo pip3 install sympy

Comment: I am using windows , not ubuntu

Comment: Open your terminal.  On windows, search "Anaconda Prompt."  Click it and type `conda install sympy`.

Answer (score 8):

Agree with Dixit.

#### First Solution:

It's okay to use `pip3 install sympy` on MacOS.

1. List item
2. Open your "Terminal".
3. Input `pip3 install sympy` and press enter.
4. It will automatically download and install the Sympy Package.

#### Second Solution:

Using git.
# Notice: Before install Sympy, it's necessary to install "mpmath".
Like the First Solution,

- 1) Open "Terminal";
- 2) Input `pip3 install mpmath`

After installing "mpmath", then,

1. List item
2. Open your "Terminal" on MacOS or "win+r", then input "cmd" in Windows.
3. Input "git clone git://github.com/sympy/sympy.git" and press enter;
4. Input "python setup.py install"

After finish installation, you can open the Python IDLE and try:

```
from sympy import Symbol, cos
x = Symbol('x')
e = 1/cos(x)
print(e.series(x, 0, 10))
# Result
# 1 + x**2/2 + 5*x**4/24 + 61*x**6/720 + 277*x**8/8064 + O(x**10)
```

If the code works, it shows that your "Sympy" package has already been installed.

Comment: sorry I am a beginer what is git

Comment: actually I am a windows user . how to do the same in windows

Comment: @acoustic python Did you try "pip3 install sympy"? It also works in Windows.

Comment: Finally I got the result. But the code is running in the spyder editor , but not running in the  python  shell. it is still showing module not found error

Comment: Maybe the package still has not been installed at the path of Python-3.6. Anyway, if you accept my answer, please tick it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In anaconda navigator:

1. Click Environments (on the left)
2. Choose your environment (if you have more than one)
3. On the middle pick "All" from dropbox ("installed" by default)
4. Write sympy in search-box on the right
5. Check the package that showed out
6. Click apply

Comment: I could not able to see the apply button

Comment: Its, not showing in my anaconda window.  what I have to do

Answer (score 0):

To use conda install, open the Anaconda Prompt and enter the *conda install sympy* command.

Alternatively, navigate to the scripts sub-directory in the Anaconda directory, and run *pip install sympy*.